# Yet another variation of the 'escaping single/double quotes for a sed command' issue

Tags: php, sed, escaping

The following 2 lines of PHP work fine:

```
exec("/bin/sed --in-place 's/_SINGLE_QUOTE_HERE_/SQ/' " . $fileSpec);
exec("/bin/sed --in-place 's/_DOUBLE_QUOTE_HERE_/DQ/' " . $fileSpec);
```

So, if the file has the following text:

```
I am 6_SINGLE_QUOTE_HERE_ 4_DOUBLE_QUOTE_HERE_ tall.
```

After executing the above code, the file then contains:

```
I am 6SQ 4DQ tall.
```

But, clearly, I want to have:

```
I am 6' 4" tall.
```

Problem is, the single/double quotes themselves mess things up.

I have tried this, but it fails:

```
exec("/bin/sed --in-place 's/_SINGLE_QUOTE_HERE_/\x27/' " . $fileSpec);
exec("/bin/sed --in-place 's/_DOUBLE_QUOTE_HERE_/\x22/' " . $fileSpec);
```

I have also tried this, but it fails too:

```
exec("/bin/sed --in-place 's/_SINGLE_QUOTE_HERE_/\'/' " . $fileSpec);
exec("/bin/sed --in-place 's/_DOUBLE_QUOTE_HERE_/\"/' " . $fileSpec);
```

Thanks in advance for a solution to this.

EDIT: Following added.

OK, this works for single quote:

```
exec("/bin/sed --in-place 's/_SINGLE_QUOTE_HERE_/'\''/g' " . $program);
```

Still having issues with the double quote. THis does NOT work:

```
exec("/bin/sed --in-place 's/_DOUBLE_QUOTE_HERE_/'\"'/g' " . $program);
```

Comment: As a way to avoid quoting issues, have you considered: `exec("/bin/sed --in-place --file=/path/to/script " . $fileSpec);` where `/path/to/script` has the raw `sed` command?

Comment: Brilliant idea - and I was excited to try it - but it failed too. :(

For clarity, I first tested with the sed command in the separate file as: s/_DOUBLE_QUOTE_HERE_/DQ/ and that worked, but when I went with s/_DOUBLE_QUOTE_HERE_/\"/ it failed. So, it doesn't avoid the quoting issues.

Comment: I just tested it and it works for me, either with or without the escape before the single or double quote.  I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1.  Are you on a non-GNU sed?

Comment: By the way, I did use `s/_SINGLE_QUOTE_HERE_/'/g` with the `g`.  Otherwise, only one substitution is made per line.

Comment: John, I just checked, and I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1. Ugh. I have very little hair left to pull out. Let me take a fresh look at it.

Comment: So, it works now for the single quote. I was missing a ' symbol. See edit in question. Still can't get the double quote to work.

Comment: My `/path/to/script` has two lines, one for single quotes and the second for double quotes: `s/_DOUBLE_QUOTE_HERE_/"/g`.  Both worked.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP or its quoting rules but note that one backslash may not be enough.  In your revised command, you need to escape the the double quote from PHP.  But then PHP passes it to the shell and you will need to have the double-quote also escaped from the shell.  If `\"` escapes the `"` from PHP, the `\` will be removed before PHP passes the expression to the shell.  To pass a literal `\` to the shell, does it have to be escaped in PHP?  If so, do you need to put `\\\"` in your command so that PHP passes `\"` to the shell?

Comment: The \\\" didn't work either. :(

John - when you say it worked for you, are you executing from the command line, or inside a PHP file?

Comment: I did `sed --in-place --file=/path/to/script filename` from the command line. However, I cannot imagine any rational way that PHP would interfere with `sed` commands in a file _that PHP will never open_.  PHP won't even know that `/path/to/script` is a file name.  It is `sed` that interprets its arguments and opens that file.

Comment: John, your comment; 'However, I cannot imagine any rational way that PHP would interfere with sed commands in a file that PHP will never open.' made me realize I was making a bad assumption. Sure enough, the bug was downstream from this sed command, and the sed command was working fine. It just appeared to be the issue, since the single quote worked. Thanks for hanging in there with me.